# EasyGUI and Python if/else and loop

Tags: python, easygui

I seem to be having some issues with my if/else statements and EasyGUI choice box. I know that if the user presses "Cancel", it returns "None". My code always enters the "Else" statement. Also, my second For loop doesn't seem to be iterating. Is there a better way to select the object (country name) that I want? Here's my code so far, with debugging output.

UPDATE: The issue was the fact that I was using a Mac for some reason. I used my PC, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Are you sure it returns the string `'None'` and not `None`? Have you tried `if choice == None:` or `if choice is None:`?

Comment: choice != 'None, choice = None! str vs builtin None.

Comment: About the second loop: Seems like your `csvdict` iterator is exhausted after the first loop. Try creating a new iterator or copy the contents to a list if it's not too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ferg.org/easygui/easygui.html#-choicebox), `choicebox` returns `None` then the cancel button is pressed, and not the string `'None'`. Change your condition to `if choice is None:` and it should work.

The problem with your second `for` loop is that `csvdict` is an iterator which is exhausted after you use it in your first `for` loop. You could either create a new iterator, or store the contents of the file in a list, or dictionary, if it is not too much data. You already did this for the `country` field, but you seem to need all the fields. The best might be to create a `dict` mapping the `country` names to lists holding the other fields, so you can quickly access them instead of having to loop over all the contries again.

```
// instead of your first for loop
choices = dict()
for line in csvdict:
    choices[line['Country']] = line
...
// instead of your second for loop
if choice in choices:
    line = choices[choice]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first part of your code works perfectly. I'm having a different issue with your second bit of code. When it runs, it says:
    line = choices[choice]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Choice is the name of the country the user selected in the choice box.

Comment: Oh, right, now I see it. Are you sure you changed to first for loop so it creates a dictionary mapping country names to the rest of the information? It seems like `choices` is still a plain old list in your case.

Comment: Oh, I see where you changed that now. I'm getting this error for that code:     choices[line['Country']] = line
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Did you change the line above the loop to make `choices` a dictionary? `choices = dict()` And just in case you are getting this as your next error, change `choicebox(msg, title, choices)` to `choicebox(msg, title, list(choices))`

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this.`if choice is None:`  worked for me.